# Attach multiple files to email in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, email-attachments, cakephp-2.3

I want to attach 5 dynamic text file in mail but not working.

I send single attachment in email working perfect my code is :

```
  $Email->attachments('path/to/example.txt');
```

But i send multiple attachment in email not working.

My code is :

```
$Email->attachments('path/to/example.txt','path/to/example1.txt','path/to/example3.txt','abs/path/to/example4.txt','path/to/example5.txt');
```

Comment: You may want to have a closer look at the docs first, and check how the `attachments()` method is ment to be used. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly - thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice.My cake php version is 2.3.

Comment: I check attachment file docs but not defined how to send multiple attachment.And also my singe email attachment working fine.only not working multiple attachments.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for multiple attachment :

```
$Email->attachments(array(
            'example.txt' => array(
                'file' => 'path/to/example.txt',
                'mimetype' => 'text/plain'
            ),
example1.txt' => array(
                'file' => 'path/to/example1.txt',
                'mimetype' => 'text/plain'
            ),
example3.txt' => array(
                'file' => 'path/to/example3.txt',
                'mimetype' => 'text/plain'
            ),
example4.txt' => array(
                'file' => 'path/to/example4.txt',
                'mimetype' => 'text/plain'
            ),
example5.txt' => array(
                'file' => 'path/to/example5.txt',
                'mimetype' => 'text/plain'
            )

        ));
```

Comment: Unless you are having issues with `mimetype` or want to rename the attached files this array structure is a bit overkill for attaching multiple files and creates more code than necessary so is harder to maintain. You only need to specify an array of the filepaths as [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34761362/311992).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$Email->attachments(
    array(
       'path/to/example.txt',
       'path/to/example1.txt',
       'path/to/example3.txt',
       'abs/path/to/example4.txt',
       'path/to/example5.txt'
   )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments) the `attachments` method takes an array as the first parameter so your code should look like:-

```
$Email->attachments(array(
    'path/to/example.txt',
    'path/to/example1.txt',
    'path/to/example3.txt',
    'abs/path/to/example4.txt',
    'path/to/example5.txt'
));
```

This is also clearly stated in the [API documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeEmail.html#$_attachments) (always worth checking).

If you look at the actual code for `attachments()` you'll see that if you pass just a string for the first parameter it gets cast as an `array`. Your code isn't working as the method doesn't take multiple parameters.

Comment: Not working for multiple attachment.working fine for single attachment.

Comment: Not sure why as this is how it should works and is how I've used it in the past.