# CakePHP 3: Sending Multiple Attachments through A Email

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, email-attachments, cakephp-3.x

I want to attach multiple files while sending email in CakePHP3.x.

Here is my data & tried Like so:

```
$files = [
(int) 0 => [
    'getFileName' => '1568016275_452872.xlsx',
    'getOriginalFileName' => 'DID Check.xlsx',
    'destinationPath' => '\webroot\/upload/files/'
],
(int) 1 => [
    'getFileName' => '1568016275_430107.csv',
    'getOriginalFileName' => 'clists.csv',
    'destinationPath' => '\webroot\/upload/files/'
]
```

]

```
$email->setAttachments($files)->send();
```

I also tried but only send the last one in the email message:

```
foreach($files as $file){
    $email->setAttachments([$file['getOriginalFileName'] => $file['destinationPath'].$file['getFileName']])
}
```

Can't understand, need help and thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to reformat your files array exactly as shown here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34761944/1309690

Comment: @ascsoftw reformatting the files array is working. Thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Email::setAttachments()` overwrites all info about previous attachments. So looping through your files and calling `setAttachments()` for each one will result in only the last one being sent.

To solve this, you can use either `Email::addAttachments()`, which will just add attachments without overwriting current data, or prepare your array of attachments first and then set it once using `setAttachments()`.

Further info:

[Cake\Mailer\Email::addAttachments()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Mailer.Email.html#_addAttachments)

[Cake\Mailer\Email::setAttachments()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Mailer.Email.html#_setAttachments)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. reformatting the files array also works like given above.